# Seikh on the 169th floor

Tags: usage

Is the following sentence correct?

> Last night I dreamed I was a Sheikh on the 169th floor of Burj Khalifa.

I think it should be:

> Last night I dreamed I was a Sheikh **(standing/living)** on the 169th floor of Burj Khalifa.

Comment: You should [tell where your text comes from](https://onlinetyari.com/question-bank/question-a-last-night-i-dreamb-i-was-a-sheikh-i7172.html). Please don't keep it a mystery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing grammatically wrong with the sentence

> Last night I dreamed I was a Sheikh on the 169th floor of Burj Khalifa.

except that I am inclined to think that "Sheikh" should not be capitalized when it is not associated with any person's name or specific geographic title.

You can consider that a participle verb form such as "standing" or "living" has been elided, byt English permits such elision quite freely, and in this case the meaning remains reasonably clear.

Comment: Well, except that those two would have different meanings. It may be that in the OP's language the equivalent of  _a sheikh on the 169th floor of Burj Khalifa_ would imply somebody living there.

Comment: Virtually any verb could fit: _standing, sitting, sleeping, reading, bathing, visiting, living_. We'd need to hear more about the dream. But I think this answer is correct, we don't need to put the verb in this sentence; more information could be supplied in subsequent text: _Last night I dreamed I was a Sheikh on the 169th floor of Burj Khalifa. I was waiting for my host to come out of his bedroom, while admiring the exotic fish I saw in his large aquarium_.